# Clearing specific fragments from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have 3 fragments in my app: [a]->[b]->[c]. first fragment a is added, then it is replaced with b and then b is replaced with c. when the user is in fragment b he can go back to fragment a by pressing back button, but when in fragment c, fragments a and b must not be accessible with back button (pressing back button must close all fragments).

I have tried using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(name, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

but it pops all fragments from the top (current fragment) to the specified fragment which is not good idea. any simple solution?!

Comment: You can use FragmentTransaction.add method when adding Fragment B, and use FragmentTransaction.replace when adding Fragment C

Comment: and then when user presses back button in fragment c fragment b will pop back which is not desired

Comment: If you are adding first fragment to backstack and fragments B and C are replaced that is okay. Now when you press back button you can check backstack count using fragment manager and then you can just popback all the fragments by iterating for loop.